# An error when compiling using curlpp

Tags: curl, compiler-errors, undefined-reference, curlpp

I tried to compile first [simple example](http://curlpp.org/index.php/examples/47-example-00), and see compile error: undefined reference to `curlpp::Cleanup::Cleanup()'

In linker options i wrote `curl-config --libs`, in command line

$ curl-config --libs

-lcurl

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there are many errors like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to link your program against plain-C curl (`-lcurl`), but against curlpp! Use `-lcurlpp` instead. You may also call `curlpp-config --libs`.

Don't forget: `curl` (without "pp") is a C library, the C++ library is called `curlpp`